# Jquery autocomplete fill multiple fields

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

How can I split autocomplete json return and fill every field according to the selected option? Basically what I want is to fill the name and lastname fields according to the found phone number.
Here's my jquery code:

```
$(document).on("focus","#phone",  function() {
$(this).autocomplete({
    source: 'autocomplete.php',
    minLength: 5,
select: function (event, ui) {
    $('#phone').val(ui.item.phone);
    $("#lastname").val(ui.item.lastname);
    $("#name").val(ui.item.name);
}
});
})
```

And here is my php:

```
$keyword = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['term']);
$search_param = "{$keyword}%";
$sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE phone LIKE ?");
$sql->bind_param("s",$search_param);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
$data = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data = array('phone' => $row['phone'],'lastname' => $row['lastname'], 'name' => $row['name'], 'address' => $row['address']);
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
$sql->close();
```

Wheen I try to enter the phone number, it returns not only the phone number, but also the name and lastname, and nothing happens when I click it :(
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Why do you not add items to `$data` but rewrite it? Use `$data[] = $row...`

Comment: Thanks, now get array in return though. Hm, how can I split it?

Comment: Why don't you use `console.log(ui.item)` in the `select` method to debug it?

Comment: Console log returns nothing, though rows are found and jquery returns number of items found. There's probably a problem with my jquery code, but I'm new to it.